# Ruby (Monkey Patching Array)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, rspec

I'm having a problem with Monkey Patching an Array Class. This assignment had **8 specs**  to be met.

I'm only going to give you the RSpecs and written requirements for the part that I'm having trouble w/ since everything else seems to be passing.

---

Here are the written requirements for the Array Class Monkey Patch:

- Write a new `new_map` method that is called on an instance of the `Array` class. It should use the array it's called on as an implicit (`self`) argument, but otherwise behave identically. (**INCOMPLETE**)
- Write a new_select! method that behaves like the select, but mutates the array on which it's called. It can use Ruby's built-in collection select method. (**COMPLETE**)

---

Here are the RSpecs that need to be met regarding the Array class:

> Note: "returns an array with updated values" Is the only Spec not passing.

```
describe Array do
  describe '#new_map' do
    it "returns an array with updated values" do
      array = [1,2,3,4]
      expect( array.new_map(&:to_s) ).to eq( %w{1 2 3 4} )
      expect( array.new_map{ |e| e + 2 } ).to eq( [3, 4, 5, 6] )
    end

    it "does not call #map" do
      array = [1,2,3,4]
      array.stub(:map) { '' }
      expect( array.new_map(&:to_s) ).to eq( %w{1 2 3 4} )
    end

    it "does not change the original array" do
      array = [1,2,3,4]
      expect( array.new_map(&:to_s) ).to eq( %w{1 2 3 4} )
      expect( array ).to eq([1,2,3,4])
    end
  end

  describe '#new_select!' do
    it "selects according to the block instructions" do
      expect( [1,2,3,4].new_select!{ |e| e > 2 } ).to eq( [3,4] )
      expect( [1,2,3,4].new_select!{ |e| e < 2 } ).to eq( [1] )
    end

    it "mutates the original collection" do
      array = [1,2,3,4]
      array.new_select!(&:even?)
      expect(array).to eq([2,4])
    end
  end
end
```

---

My code:

```
class Array
  def new_map 
    new_array = []
    self.each do |num|
      new_array << num.to_s
    end
    new_array
  end
  
  def new_select!(&block)
    self.select!(&block)
  end
end
```

Comment: This almost identical to your very first question and it's resulting in almost identical answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Ruby Array Class:
>
> ```
> map { |item| block } → new_ary
> ```

A `block` is like a method, and you specify a block after a method call, for example:

```
[1, 2, 3].map() {|x| x*2} #<---block
           ^
           |
       method call(usually written without the trailing parentheses)
```

The block is implicitly sent to the method, and inside the method you can call the block with `yield`.

`yield` -> calls the block specified after a method call. In ruby, `yield` is equivalent to `yield()`, which is conceptually equivalent to calling the block like this: `block()`.

`yield(x)` -> calls the block specified after a method call sending it the argument x, which is conceptually equivalent to calling the block like this: `block(x)`.

So, here is how you can implement new_map():

```
class Array
  def new_map
    result = []

    each do |item|
      result << yield(item)
    end

    result

  end
end

arr = [1, 2, 3].new_map {|x| x*2}
p arr

--output:--
[2, 4, 6]
```

This comment is a bit advanced, but you don't actually have to write `self.each()` to call the each() method inside new_map().  All methods are called by some object, i.e. the object to the left of the dot, which is called the *receiver*.  For instance, when you write:

```
self.each {....}
```

self is the receiver of the method call each().

If you do not specify a `receiver` and just write:

```
each {....}
```

...then for the receiver ruby uses whatever object is assigned to the `self` variable at that moment.  Inside new_map() above, ruby will assign the Array that calls the new_map() method to self, so each() will step through the items in that Array.

You have to be a little bit careful with the self variable because ruby constantly changes the value of the self variable without telling you.  So, you have to *know* what ruby has assigned to the self variable at any particular point in your code--which comes with experience.  Although, if you ever want to know what object ruby has assigned to self at some particular point in your code, you can simply write:

```
puts self
```

Experienced rubyists will crow and cluck their tongues if they see you write `self.each {...}` inside new_map(), but in my opinion ***code clarity*** trumps ***code trickiness***, and because it makes more sense to beginners to write self there, go ahead and do it.  When you get a little more experience and want to show off, then you can eliminate explicit receivers when they aren't required.  It's sort of the same situation with explicit returns:

```
def some_method
    ...
    return result
end
```

and implicit returns:

```
def some_method
    ...
    result
end
```

Note that you *could* write new_map() like this:

```
class Array
  def new_map(&my_block)  #capture the block in a variable
    result = []

    each do |item|
      result << my_block.call(item) #call the block
    end

    result

  end
end

arr = [1, 2, 3].new_map {|x| x*2}
p arr

--output:--
[2, 4, 6]
```

Compare that to the example that uses yield().  When you use yield(), it's as if ruby creates a parameter variable named `yield` for you in order to capture the block. However, with yield you use a different syntax to call the block, namely `()`, or if their are no arguments for the block, you can eliminate the parentheses--just like you can when you call a method.  On the other hand, when you create your own parameter variable to capture a block, e.g. `def new_map(&my_block)`, you have to use a different syntax to call the block:

1. `my_block.call(arg1, ...)`

or:

2. `myblock[arg1, ...]`

Note that #2 is just like the syntax for calling a method--except that you substitute `[]` in place of `()`.

Once again, experienced rubyists will use yield to call the block instead of capturing the block in a parameter variable.  However, there are situations where you will need to capture the block in a parameter variable, e.g. if you want to pass the block to yet another method.

Comment: Thanks @7stud. Great detailed answer this really helps clarify this block/yield thing for me. I really appreciate it. I understand that self is implicit now. Once the exercises are solved it unlocks their answers and there was no use of `self`

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the spec here:

```
it "returns an array with updated values" do
  array = [1,2,3,4]
  expect( array.new_map(&:to_s) ).to eq( %w{1 2 3 4} )
  expect( array.new_map{ |e| e + 2 } ).to eq( [3, 4, 5, 6] )
end
```

It looks like they just want you to re-write `Array.map` so that it will work with any given block. In your implementation you are telling the method to work in a very specific way, namely to call `.to_s` on all of the array elements. But you don't want it to *always* stringify the array elements. You want it to do to each element whatever block is provided when the method is called. Try this:

```
class Array
  def new_map 
    new_array = []
    each do |num|
      new_array << yield(num)
    end
    new_array
  end
end
```

Notice in my example that the method definition doesn't specify any particular operation to be performed on each element of `self`. It simply loops over each element of the array, yields the element (`num`) to whatever block was passed when `.new_map` was called, and shovels the result into the `new_array` variable.

With that implementation of `.new_map` and given `array = [1,2,3,4]`, you can call either `array.new_map(&:to_s)` (**the block** is where the arbitrary operation to be performed on each element of the array is specified) and get `["1","2","3","4"]` or you can call `array.new_map { |e| e + 2 }` and get `[3,4,5,6]`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and especially for the description @sixty4bit it really helped clarify this for me. Especially the use of yield which I've been struggling with. Cheers.

Comment: FWIW, this is almost identical to [the definition of map](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/kernel/common/enumerable.rb#L45-L55) that rubinius uses.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to say a few words about `new_select!`.

**select vs select!**

You have:

```
class Array
  def new_select!(&block)
    self.select!(&block)
  end
end
```

which you could instead write:

```
class Array
  def new_select!
    self.select! { |e| yield(e) }
  end
end
```

This uses the method [Array#select!](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-select-21). You said [Array#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-select) could be used, but made no mention of `select!`. If you cannot use `select!`, you must do something like this:

```
class Array
  def new_select!(&block)
    replace(select(&block)) 
  end
end
```

Let's try it:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
a.new_select! { |n| n.odd? }
  #=> [1, 3, 5] 
a #=> [1, 3, 5]
```

**Explicit vs implicit receivers**

Notice that I have written this without any explicit receivers for the methods [Array#replace](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-replace) and `Array#select`. When there is no explicit receiver, Ruby assumes that it is `self`, which is the `a`. Therefore, Ruby evaluates `replace(select(&block))` as though it were written with explicit receivers:

```
self.replace(self.select(&block))
```

It's up to you to decide if you want to include `self.`. Some Rubiests do, some don't. You'll notice that `self.` is not included in Ruby built-in methods implemented in Ruby. One other thing: `self.` is required in some situations to avoid ambiguity. For example, if `taco=` is the setter for an instance variable `@taco`, you must write `self.taco = 7` to tell Ruby you are referring to the setter method. If you write `taco = 7`, Ruby will assume you want to create a local variable `taco` and set its value to 7.

**Two forms of select!**

Is your method `new_select!` a direct replacement for `select!`? That is, are the two methods functionally equivalent? If you look at the docs for `Array#select!`, you will see it has two forms, the one you have mimicked, and another that you have not implemented.

If `select!` is not given a block, it returns an enumerator. Now why would you want to do that? Suppose you wish to write:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
a.select!.with_index { |n,i| i < 2 }
  #=> [1, 2]
```

Has `select!` been given a block? No, so it must return an enumerator, which becomes the receiver of the method [Enumerator#with_index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index).

Let's try it:

```
enum0 = a.select!
  #=> #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:select!>
```

Now:

```
enum1 = enum0.with_index
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:select!>:with_index>
```

You can think of `enum1` as a "compound enumerator". Look carefully at the description (above) of the object Ruby returns when you define `enum1`.

We can see the elements of the enumerator by converting it to an array:

```
enum1.to_a
  # => [[1, 0], [2, 1], [3, 2], [4, 3], [5, 4]]
```

Each of these five elements is passed to the block and assigned to the block variables by [Enumerator#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-each) (which calls [Array#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each)).

Enough of that, but the point is that having methods return enumerators when no block is given is what allows us to chain methods.

You do not have a test that ensures `new_select!` returns an enumerator when no block is given, so maybe that's not expected, but why not give it a go?

```
class Array
  def new_select!(&block)
    if block_given?
      replace(select(&block))
    else
      to_enum(:new_select!)
    end
  end
end
```

Try it:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
a.new_select! { |n| n.odd? }
  #=> [1, 3, 5] 
a #=> [1, 3, 5] 

a = [1,2,3,4,5]
enum2 = a.new_select!
  #=> #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:new_select!> 
enum2.each { |n| n.odd? }
  #=> [1, 3, 5] 
a #=> [1, 3, 5]

a = [1,2,3,4,5]
enum2 = a.new_select!
  #=> #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:new_select!> 
enum2.with_index.each { |n,i| i>2 }
  #=> [4, 5] 
a #=> [4, 5]
```